# Not able to show pdf inside HTML .It getting downloaded fro Firefox and chrome working well for Safari

Tags: html, pdf

I am trying to show my pdf in HTML code.My pdf is having link inside it.I am able to show pdf using below code

```
<object data="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

But same is not working for Firefox and Chrome.They download the file not showing it.I also used iframe and embeded but have the same issue.

Comment: This happen when browser doesn't understand file MIME type of pdf is set while uploading or creating. wherever file is there check MIME is set to `application/pdf` or not

Comment: @aviboy2006 The file is in cloud so i don't think that is the issue....

Comment: it might be issue i have issue this in AWS S3  file MIME type.